# Procedure to award every 3rd person

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Im working on a stored procedure, which should reward every 3rd person with a extra bonus on his current credit. Amount of bonus and (3rd person) option should be parameterized. Among is a my current code, but when I try to execute this with SQLFiddle, I get always the error `Incorrect syntax near 'INTEGER'.` - but I can't find out the mistake in my code. I'm using MS SQL Server 2014.

```
    CREATE TABLE Customer (
        custnr      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
        name        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        firstname   VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        credit      DECIMAL(12,2) 
    );

    CREATE PROCEDURE awardBonus
        @position       INTEGER;
        @bonus          DECIMAL(5,2) 
    AS 
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @creditCustomer DECIMAL(12,2);
        DECLARE customer_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT custnr 
        FROM Customer
        ORDER BY custnr ASC;

        OPEN customer_cursor;

        FETCH NEXT FROM customer_cursor INTO @custnr;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
            BEGIN

                IF (@custnr % @position = 0) 
                    BEGIN 
                        SELECT @creditCustomer = credit 
                        FROM Customer 
                        WHERE custnr = @custnr;

                        SET @creditCustomer = @creditCustomer + @bonus;

                        UPDATE Customer 
                        SET credit = @creditCustomer
                        WHERE custnr = @custnr;
                    END; 
                FETCH NEXT FROM customer_cursor INTO @custnr;
            END;

        CLOSE customer_cursor;      
        DEALLOCATE customer_cursor;

    END;

EXECUTE awardBonus 3, 100
```

Comment: Please post sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `;` in the parameter list:

```
@position       INTEGER;
```

Also, you should declare first `@custnr`:

```
DECLARE @custnr INT;
```

You also have an invalid column name error in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY knr ASC;
```

should be:

```
ORDER BY custnr ASC;
```

---

## Not so fast!

You can rewrite this in a set-based fashion and remove the use of `CURSOR`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE awardBonus
    @position   INTEGER,
    @bonus      DECIMAL(5,2) 
AS 
BEGIN

WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY custnr)
    FROM Customer
)
UPDATE Cte
    SET credit  = credit + @bonus
WHERE
    rn % @position = 0

END
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me another way - is cursor already deprecated ?

Comment: `CURSOR` is not deprecated. It's generally avoided due to performance. Always write queries in a set-based fashion.

Answer (score 2):

`CREATE PROCEDURE awardBonus
        @position       INTEGER;
        @bonus          DECIMAL(5,2)`

there is a semicolon after integer should be a comma

corrected version

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE awardBonus
    @position       INTEGER,
    @bonus          DECIMAL(5,2)
```

On a different note, how are you selecting the 3rd person, should this be a random selection or ordered? And why are you using the Cursor, the set based solutions seems to be a better choice. In both random or not cases you could construct the query using ROW_NUMBER() and select 3rd record for example.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a `;` where you need a `,`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE awardBonus
        @position       INTEGER;
        @bonus          DECIMAL(5,2)
```

Furthermore, `CREATE PROCEDURE` must be the only statement in a batch. So you'll have to create the table in a separate batch.

Also, you use `ORDER BY knr ASC`, `knr` does not exist.

You also use a variable `@custnr` which is not declared.

Comment: Thanks - "create the table in a seperate batch", can I realize this with SQLFiddle?

Comment: @Matej, put the query terminator in between. You can see which query terminator is used on the 4th button in the schema panel.

Comment: @FelixPamittan I tried - "'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch."  I have no idea, what im doing wrong. Where should I set the terminator?